# Local behavior of Brownian Motion

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, brownian-motion, holder-spaces

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\Bbb P)$ be a complete probability space.
Let us consider a standard Brownian Motion $B=(B_t)_{t\ge0}$ on this space.

We know that its trajectories are $\alpha$-Holder continuous for every $\alpha<1/2$, and moreover that a.s. $B_0=0$.

Thus I was asking myself (even looking at the many realizations that can be found on the web):  is it possible to control the behaviour of the trajectories near $0$?

I mean, I conjectured that $\forall \epsilon>0\;\;\exists\delta>0$ such that
$$
t^{1/2+\epsilon}\le|B_t|\le t^{1/2-\epsilon}\;\;\forall t\in[0,\delta].
$$
This seems reasonable, but I don't know how to prove or disprove it.

**EDIT: GENERALIZATION**

If $B^H=(B_t^H)_{t\ge0}$ is a fractional Brownian Motion of Hurst parameter $0<H<1$, is it possible to prove that
$$
t^{H+\epsilon}\le|B_t^H|\le t^{H-\epsilon}\;\;\forall t\in[0,\delta]?
$$

Comment: Not a.s. no; with positive probability $B_t$ is arbitrarily large. Recall that it is $N(0,t)$ distributed at each time. So somehow you should have an $\alpha$ as well to control the rarity of the event you are prohibiting. Or a random constant factor that is not uniformly bounded but presumably has small enough tails that its MGF exists.

Comment: Isn't this very related to Levy's modulus of continuity theorem? Or maybe I'm a little off.

Comment: @Ian: I agree that $B_t$ can be arbitrarily large, but... what about neighbors of zero? I mean: choosing a distance from $t=0$ small as we want, haven't us the possibility to control the trajectories?

Comment: The left hand side of your conjecture doesn't really make sense since $|B_t|=0$ for arbitrarily small $t>0$.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the [law of the iterated logarithm for Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm).

With probability one,

$$\limsup_{h\downarrow 0}{|B(h)|\over \sqrt{2h\log\log(1/h)}}=1.$$

This is Corollary 5.3 (top of page 121) in  *Brownian motion* by Peter Mörters and Yuval Peres. You can download the 
book at yuvalperes.com/brbook.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I know The LII holds as $\limsup=1$ and as $\liminf=-1$ when the BM is taken without absolute value.
I'd say the $\limsup$ you wrote holds as a classical limit. I'm I right?

Comment: @Joe I don't understand this comment. What is a "classical limit" and what are you asking?

Comment: When limsup=liminf then the limit exists and coincide with the limsup. Now, since I know that $\limsup_{h\to0^+}\frac{B_t}{\sqrt{\cdots}}=1$ and  $\liminf_{h\to0^+}\frac{B_t}{\sqrt{\cdots}}=-1$, is it true that  $\limsup_{h\to0^+}\frac{|B_t|}{\sqrt{\cdots}}=\liminf_{h\to0^+}\frac{|B_t|}{\sqrt{\cdots}}=1$?

Comment: No. As I mentioned in a comment on your original post the lim inf is 0, not 1.

Comment: Ok many thanks Byron